# Getting multiple strings from SNMPWALK requests via Bash but unsure how to format for output

Tags: arrays, bash, terminal, string-parsing

I haven't had too much experience with bash yet and I'm learning as I go. At work we're needing to use SNMP to pull data from wireless access points. I've been tasked to make a script to loop through a few thousand access points.

---

I'm pulling multiple strings of data by sequential requests via SNMPWALK. This is how I've set up my input:

```
IAP=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapName -Oqv)
MODEL=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::arrayModel -Oqv | cut -d ',' -f1)
CHANNEL=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapChannel -Oqv)
MAXHOUR=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsHour -Oqv)
MAXDAY=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsDay -Oqv)
MAXWEEK=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsWeek -Oqv)
MAXMONTH=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsMonth -Oqv)
MAXYEAR=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsYear -Oqv)
MAC=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMacAddress -Oqv)
```

Here's an example of input as printed via `echo`:

```
iap1
iap2
iap3
iap4
iap5
iap6
iap7
iap8

XR4820

6
100
11
149
64
112
36
161

9
2
7
2
2
1
3
2

11
5
9
4
8
3
3
3

22
9
21
4
12
4
16
5

24
23
21
5
12
8
20
11

24
23
21
5
12
8
20
11

00:0f:7d:ea:b1:00-01
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:10-11
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:20-21
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:30-31
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:40-41
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:50-51
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:60-61
00:0f:7d:ea:b1:70-71
```

I need to take the data and output it to CSV. The problem is that I have to get them in order (ex. MODEL[0],CHANNEL[0],. . .,MAC[0],MODEL[1],CHANNEL[1], . . .). I can't seem to do this properly.

I made an attempt to use `IFS` as suggested by other answers in stackoverflow. I tried creating a `for` loop to then iterate through the elements:

```
IAP=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapName -Oqv)

if [ "$IAP" != "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]
then

    MODEL=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::arrayModel -Oqv | cut -d ',' -f1)

    CHANNEL=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapChannel -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a CHANNEL <<< "$CHANNEL"

    MAXHOUR=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsHour -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a MAXHOUR <<< "$MAXHOUR"

    MAXDAY=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsDay -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a MAXDAY <<< "$MAXDAY"

    MAXWEEK=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsWeek -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a MAXWEEK <<< "$MAXWEEK"

    MAXMONTH=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsMonth -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a MAXMONTH <<< "$MAXMONTH"

    MAXYEAR=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMaxStationsYear -Oqv)
    IFS=' ' read -a MAXYEAR <<< "$MAXYEAR"

    MAC=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::iapMacAddress -Oqv)      
    IFS=' ' read -a MAC <<< "$MAC"

    for ((i=0; i<${#IAP[@]}; ++i));
    do
        ia=${IAP[$i]}
        m=${MAC[$i]}
        c=${CHANNEL[$i]}
        h=${MAXHOUR[$i]}
        d=${MAXDAY[$i]}
        w=${MAXWEEK[$i]}
        mon=${MAXMONTH[$i]}
        y=${MAXYEAR[$i]}

        if [ -n "$m" ]
        then

            TEMP="$MODEL,$ia,$c,$h,$d,$w,$mon,$y"
            if [ $i -gt 1 ]
            then
                OUTPUT=",$OUTPUT,$TEMP"
            else
                OUTPUT="$TEMP"
            fi

        fi
    done
```

However, this is the output:

```
XR4820,iap1
iap2
iap3
iap4
iap5
iap6
iap7
iap8,11,8,11,11,11,11
```

While it should be:

> iap1,6,9,11,22,24,24,iap2,100,2,5,9,23,23,iap3,...

**Summarized:**

My input is a handful of long strings that I need to parse and send the elements out to a .CSV file. They need to be in order, ie. get elements '0' from each, then elements '1' and so forth. I created a loop that isn't working but still prints some of the data. In my naive opinion the best solution is to convert each variable into an array and iterate through the elements in sequential order.

- What is the proper way of taking each input variable and turning it into an array? The input for each variable can range from 2 to 16. I need to account for this dynamic sizing
- Please look at my `for` loop. How can I simplify it while maintaining the output format? It's a mess from multiple changes
- If I used `IFS` to take the data and place it into an array, what would I need to change?

Comment: I"m not answering your Q ;-), but responding to what I see a alot of redundant code. You should be able to do something more directly, like `read -a MAC <(snmpbulkwalk -v 2c ....)`. Also can you get multiple outputs from 1 call, maybe `snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE XIRRUS-MIB::arrayModel XIRRUS-MIB::iapChannel ... -Oqv`. That would reduce the load of the process enormously.

Comment: @shellter Thank you! My whole entry was long but you can sense a bit of desperation :P | I haven't tried multiple commands yet. Would `snmpbulkwalk` be better? I can't see a difference but I've read that it's more efficient when pulling large chunks of data. As for `read -a MAC <(snmpbulkwalk -v 2c ....)` I'll make an attempt and see how it works. That's perfect for getting me started! Thank you!

Comment: sorry, don't know about `snmp*walk` (at all), will see what G. tells me ; -)

Comment: @shellter No worries. For now `snmpwalk` will do the job just fine. I just realized I used my old code with `snmpbulkwalk` instead of `snmpwalk`. Oops! Time to edit that

Comment: now that I see these are `tree`s of information being returned, less confident that you can fiddle this, but `read -a MAC <(snmp....)`, will put all output from that command into anl array variable MAC, that you can access as `${MAC[1]}, ${MAC[2]}`, etc with an open-ended limit to `MAC[n]`.  You can get that value with `${#MAC}`. Got to go. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your help! I won't be back at work until Tuesday to try it out but I'll see if I have time this weekend to tinker with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a variable (space delimited) an array by`var=( $var )`, but I didn't get your questions completely.

If you edited your post and summarized the things that you want at the end of it, that would be helpful.

**Edit (based on the comments):**

In the case that your fields are seperated by '\n':

```
var1=`echo $var1 | tr "\n" " "`
var1=( $var1 )
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I was in a bit of a rush. Let me cut it down

Comment: Ok, I summarized it a bit. It looks like the input is stored with a newline carrier rather than a space between each value (ex. "3\n4" instead of "3 4"). Could I still use `var=( $var )`?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're putting a string into `var1` that then acts as a command when called, resulting in `var1=( $var1 )` to print out the contents of `var1` as though it were a command, filtering data separated by newline carriers?

Comment: `var1=( $var1 )` converts the space separated variable (var1) into an array and for `tr` you can check its man page.

Comment: Got it. I'll check out the man page before I start working on it